# Double php error: Getting error readfile(): https:// wrapper is disabled etc; error failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found

Tags: php, .htaccess

Recently for no apparent reason the readfile function has stopped working across one of the sites that I manage. The error that I'm getting in the php error logs is:

PHP Warning:  readfile(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

PHP Warning:  readfile(https://www.thedomain.com/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I have enabled allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include yet it still doesn't work. I have found another solution based on php curl library online and it works but Implementing it across the entire site is tedious as the site is enormous.

I have tried alternatives such as adding "php_value allow_url_fopen On" to the .htaccess file and adding a php.ini with "allow_url_fopen = On" and "allow_url_include = On" file in a few of the directories of pages that aren't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

`allow_url_fopen` can be changed only in the system level INI file, it can not be changed (i.e., overridden) in a `.htaccess` file or in a script via `ini_set()`. See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) for details. You can run a script containing `phpinfo();` to discover what INI file your PHP installation is loading. Look for something like:

`Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php.ini`